Wormhole metric by identification
In Matt Visser's book Lorentzian Wormholes the following metric is considered
$$ds^2 = -e^{2\phi(l)}dt^2 + dl^2 + r(l)^2 d\Omega^2 $$
The entry points of the wormhole exists at $l = -L/2, L/2$. Now, for a wormhole we must have
$$ds^2|_{l = -L/2} = ds^2|_{l = L/2}$$
which implies that
$$ e^{\phi(-L/2)}dt_{-} = e^{\phi(L/2)}dt_{+} \\ r(-L/2) = r(L/2) $$
where $t_{\pm}$ are the times are $\pm L/2$. These conditions should have been sufficient for the wormhole. However, in the book an additional condition is made where the following identification is also made (in Eq. 18.41)
$$ (t_{-}, -L/2) \equiv (t_{-} e^{\phi(-L/2)-\phi(L/2)}, L/2) $$
I do not see the point of this identificiation because the metric is already matched. This additional condition not only seems redundant but also problematic as this identification is also the reason why there is a closed timelike curve in this wormhole configuration. Without this identification, we have a perfectly reasonable wormhole without any paradoxes. Can someone explain why this identification is even needed? Also, can somebody point out if this identification was made in the original Frolov and Novikov paper because I did not find such an identification mentioned there.

Just because the metric is the same at two space-time points does not make these two points related. However, an identifaction essentially glues space time at one point, i.e. creates a bridge.

@Confuse-ray30 Isn't that taken care of when you define $d\tau = e^{\phi(-L / 2)} d t_{-}=e^{\phi(L / 2)} d t_{+}$? The 'new' coordinate time is same at two points hence the two points must be related.

I don't see where a new coordinate is defined in the question. Let's say you want spacetime to be a cylinder. Then you identify two sides of a square. This gives you the condition that on the boundary of the square, the metric must be the same (since they are the same spacetime point) AND you identify the boundary with each other.

Btw, I cannot access the paper, so... I dont think I can provide more insight. Unless you explain what "identification" means here. But I guess youd be able to answer the question at that point.

If you integrate $e^{\phi_{-}} dt_{-} = e^{\phi_{+}} dt_{+}$
you obtain (18.40), i.e. $e^{\phi_{-}}t_{-} = e^{\phi_{+}}t_{+}$. This means $t_{+} = t_{-}e^{\phi_{-} - \phi_{+}}$ and so identifying $(t_{-},-L/2)  \equiv (t_{+}, +L/2)$ means $(t_{-},-L/2)  \equiv (t_{-}e^{\phi_{-} - \phi_{+}}, +L/2)$. The reason he is doing so is explained few lines above: for the metric to be smooth means that $\sqrt{g_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu}}$ has so be smooth, so to a discontinuity in the metric component ($e^{\phi_{-}-\phi_{+}}$) we match a discontinuity in the coordinates $(t_{-},-L/2)  \equiv (t_{-}e^{\phi_{-} - \phi_{+}}, +L/2)$.
This is also done in Frolov 1991 pg. 3883 and Frolov and Novikov 1990 pg. 1062.

Can you tell me which equation?

Also, suppose we define $d\tau = e^{\phi(-L / 2)} d t_{-}=e^{\phi(L / 2)} d t_{+}$, we can instead match $(\tau, -L/2) \equiv (\tau, L/2 )$. Doesn't this make much more sense? Shouldn't the matching be done in the new 'time' coordinate rather than the old ones?
